# WordPress Mobile Theme Switcher Without Plugin (User Agent and Cookie)

Tags: php, .htaccess, mobile-phones, wordpress-theming, user-agent

I found some plugins like WP Mobile Pack, but I want to put together my own very simple theme switcher. (Just don't want any bloat.)

I have a regular WordPress theme and I also created a WordPress Mobile theme as well. These are both standard WP themes that can be activated in the dashboard.

How can I direct certain user agents directly to the mobile theme? (I don't want a mobile domain, sub-domain, or trailing directory.) www.example.com should be the domain for any visitor.

The one catch is, I also want to offer a link to let users switch back. For instance, iOS devices should go to the Mobile Theme. But if they are on the large iPad, they may want to simply use the regular site. Having some sort of cookie override the default .htaccess or PHP redirection would be useful.

Any help, specifically targeted at WP and handling WP theme switching would be truly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you look at the plugins and see how they work?  That should put you on the path.

Answer (score 0):

I would use 2 stylesheets to theme the page, and detect the browser and serve up the right css depending on what the browser is detected as. Have a look at the 'get_browser' function of PHP http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php

then just have an if statement:

```
if (preg_match('/mobile/i', $u_agent)) {
    $css = 'mobile.css';
}
```

and then just load the $css

Hope that makes some sense.

Comment: I don't think this is what he is asking. He is asking to switch THEMES, not style sheets.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create a plugin, that fires the switch theme action. Here is a reference:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_theme

I think you can try the 'after_setup_theme' hook.